# Таймер на Python

Tags: python, таймер, tkinter

Пишу небольшую утилиту на Python 2.7 + Tkinter. Понадобилось отсчитывать время между нажатиями на кнопку. Т.е. имеется кнопка, по нажатию на которую должен активироваться таймер (отсчет в секундах); при повторном нажатии прекращается отсчет времени и выводится время. Например, так:

```
from Tkinter import *  
root=Tk()
button1 = Button(root, width=5, text=".", command=timer)
button1.pack()

def timer():
  # Здесь должен быть таймер

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как и везде — запомнить время первого нажатия, вычесть его из времени второго нажатия…

[time.time](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/time.html?highlight=time#time.time)

```
currentTime = time.time()
```

Comment: Можно поподробнее - как это сделать на Python? Я до этого ни разу не имел дело с модулем time.

Comment: обновил ответ

Comment: Как будет выглядеть сама эта функция? Ещё нажатия должно быть не два, а произвольное количество (каждый раз выводится разность). Подобные вещи используются, например, в тестах на скорость кликов (вычислить разности между 2 и 1 кликом, 3 и 2 и т.д. и вывести сумму разностей).
P.S. Извините за глупые вопросы, я новичок.

Comment: @Barlog_h Лучше использовать `time.monotonic()` вместо `time.time()` (если доступно), чтобы относительную разницу во времени найти. `time.monotonic()` работает даже во время високосной секунды такой как 2017-01-01 02:59:60 MSK

Answer (score 2):

Данный вариант не блокирует сценарий выполнения скрипта. Это значит, что ты запустил таймер и он себе тихо ждет истечение времени, а программа работает дальше.

```
import threading

def timer(timeout):
    Timer = threading.Timer(timeout, func)
    Timer.start()

# timeout - время в секундах
# func - функция которая выполнится после истечения времени
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
#тут получили первый клик
CurrentTime = time.time()
while 1:
---#тут получаем все последующие клики 
---CurrentTime = time.time()-CurrentTime
---print(CurrentTime)

функция time.time() возвращает время в миллисекундах начиная с какой-то там даты
```

Comment: [PEP8 Naming Conventions][1]

не надо переменные с большой буквы называть

  [1]: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы показать время между последовательными нажатиями на кнопку (вызовами `timer()`), можно использовать [`time.monotonic()` функцию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic), значение которой не может пойти назад и не зависит от изменения системного времени:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from time import monotonic as now
from tkinter import Tk, Button

def timer(times=[now()]):
    times.append(now()) # сохраняем текущее время по нажатию кнопки
    time_diff = times[-1] - times.pop(0) # время между последними нажатиями
    button['text'] = '{:4.0f} мс'.format(1000 * time_diff) # показываем

root = Tk()
button = Button(root, text="нажми меня", command=timer)
button.pack()
# center window
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % root.winfo_pathname(root.winfo_id()))
root.mainloop()
```

Использование изменяемых значений для параметров функции по умолчанию таких как `times` список в примере не рекомендуется в общем случае. Вместо этого следует создать класс или closure, которое будут хранить значение таймера из прошлого нажатия кнопки.